# Using Firefox's 3D view, how do I scroll down the page?

Tags: firefox, websites, web-development

I'd like to scroll down while using Firefox's [3D view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View) to inspect web pages. I want to see a flat view of the footer like shown here for the top of the page:

[image: Firefox 3D default view]

The best I can do is to scroll way out, then rotate the page. That gives me this view of the footer, which is at too extreme an angle to be useful:

[image: Firefox 3D rotated view of page footer]

Scrolling to the bottom of the page first, then triggering 3D view makes no difference. I am still presented with the top of the page.

**How do I scroll down the page while keeping it flat like the top image?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get to the bottom of the page in 3D view, right click and drag, to pan down.

Comment: Perfect, tested and working.